# Error JAVA_HOME is not set while it is set

Tags: linux, react-native

When I try to run command:

```
    react-native run-android
```

I get this error:

```
Scanning folders for symlinks in /home/x/myApp/node_modules 
(10ms)
JS server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && 
./gradlew installDebug)...

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be 
found in your PATH.

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device 
connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
```

JAVA_HOME is set correctly (I think)

```
java -version
```

and

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

return correct results. Screenshot:
[image: 1]
JAVA_HOME is set in /etc/environment /etc/profile /bashrc /bash_profile

I did source /bashrc etc too

Virtual device is connected too. I'm able to open this project in android-studio and generate apk

Comment: Try restarting your PC this often helps with such issues

Comment: How is `JAVA_HOME` set exactly?

Comment: Check the value with `env | grep JAVA_HOME` instead, since `echo` won't tell you if the variable is exported

Comment: @NikosC. what do you mean? Location is shown on screenshot

Comment: @NikosC. what do you mean? Location is shown on screenshot
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-12.0.1
I changed JAVA_HOME in bashrc bash_profile and few more as I said in first post

Comment: @PLASMAchicken - thanks, checking it now

Comment: @thatotherguy - result: JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-12.0.1 - so correct

Comment: @AAAKKK Good. How about `ls -l "$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"` ? Did you set up this path recently?

Comment: I meant how did you set it, not what it's set to. Is it exported? Like `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-12.0.1`

Comment: @thatotherguy -rwxr-xr-x 1 668 668 8720 Apr  2 08:50 /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-12.0.1/bin/java

Comment: @PLASMAchicken restart didn't help

Comment: @NikosC. as I said I made changes in bashrc, bash_profile, /etc/environment. It's exported

Comment: Huh, a restart would have sorted out any issues with stale environment and gradle daemons. Are you seeing the same problem if you manually `cd android && 
./gradlew installDebug`?

Comment: @thatotherguy similar one:
"ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation."

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have java installed

after that

if your path is wrong
do this:

```
export | grep JAVA
```

THE RESULT: what java home is set to

```
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home
```

follow the path to see if the directories are correct
i did this in my terminal:

```
open /Library
```

then i went to /Java/JavaVirturalMachines turns out I had the wrong "jdk1.8.0_202.jdk" folder, there was another number... 4. you can use this command to set java_home

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Answer (score 0):

In linux you don't need to restart your PC, if you have ubuntu or a derivative the file that contains the PATH is in /etc/enviroment , check that file to see if JAVA_HOME is set there.

Aditionally, you might wanna use JDK8 , since JDK9 and 10 don't work well with react native.

Then close your session and login again

Comment: it's set in /etc/environment, printenv as I said in first post & tested on JDK8, 9 and 12 ;)
I installed react-native on windows laptop and it worked first off. Linux is sometimes really annoying